# Customize TFS Auto Builds and Deploys

Tags: tfs

We use TFS 2012 as our Source Control Repository and we also use it to deploy our Web Applications (primarily ASP .NET MVC applications with Entity Framework Code First Databases) using TFS Build and Deploy from Team Explorer within Visual Studio.

Our's is a fairly small and new setup, so up until now, we developers have been deploying code to the production servers. But from an Audit point of view, it has been decided that code installation will be handed to a separate group. At the moment, before we deploy code using TFS Automated Deploy we do a couple of steps which are manual steps
- Log on the production server, backup the individual application within IIS using IIS --> Export to export it   to a zip file.
- Stop application pool for the IIS application where new code is being installed
- Install new code from Visual Studio --> Queue new Build
- Get back on the server to restart the application pool and do tests to see if the application is working as expected.

I wondering, if anyone can guide me, if there is any way to change the Automated Build and Deploy template / process / workflow to do these manual steps before it does these steps before and after it deploys the code? Basically, the new team doing the code install to the Production Server and they will still click and install code automatically but the buid templace / process / workflow will do these steps as a part of the Build / Deploy process.

thanks

Comment: I would recommend that you hook your TFS 2012 up to Release Management as @justtfs suggests

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you can code it, Powershell, bat etc. then you can add it to the template.

Identify where in the workflow you need to add your new steps. you can then add an invoke process activity to call out to your scripts, that will do the currently manual steps.

I would have thought most of the IIS steps can be automated using powershell and iis **appcmd**

Also it may well be worth looking at Release Management 2013 as your deployment pipeline, it will give a more Auditable stream and allow for sign off to approve deployments. http://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/release-management-for-microsoft-visual-studio-vs.aspx